# How to store separately inputted numbers in same variable C++?

Tags: c++

How can I store two separately inputted numbers into one variable that stores the first number in the tens place, and then the second number in the ones place? For example...

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
cout<<"first number: ";
cin>>num1;
cout<<"second number: ";
cin>>num2;
//now the variable both should store the number 12
int both = ?????????;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int result = num1 * 10 + num2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
int both = (num1*10) + num2;
```

Example case:

If `num1` is 4, and num2 is 5:

```
both = (4*10) + 5; // 45
```

If you want more than 2 numbers, you have an option to store those input numbers to an array, then use a for loop to get your result:

```
int res = 0;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) { // N is your number of inputs
    res += num[i] * pow(10, (N-1)-i); // num is your array of numbers and pow() is a function from math library
}
```